# how to convert DateField field while returning a filtered result in DJANGO

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have the following table in `django`:

## models.py

```
class Activity(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  date_created = models.DateField()
```

here is the way i create an instance of that table

```
from datetime import date

Activity.objects.create(name="Foo", date_created=str(date.today()))
```

I know that `auto_now_add=True` can be used to store the **date** but at the moment it's out of the question and I need to find a solution exactly like the models is above.

Is there a way to format the `date_created` field while querying all instances of the table Activity using `.values()` below in the `views.py`

## views.py

```
activity = Activity.objects.filter(name="soccer").values()
```

I am currently getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable
```

```
activity = Activity.objects.filter(name="soccer").values()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `date` object itself:

```
Activity.objects.create(name="Foo", date_created=date.today())
```

> Is there a way to format the date_created field while querying all instances of the table Activity using `.values()` below in the `views.py`.

The format of a non-text objects is an *implementation detail*, nor is it the task of the database to format this. You should do this in the template, serializer, or view.

Furthermore using `.values()` is often *not* a good idea anyway. Django has a [**`DjangoJSONEncoder`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) that will encode datetime with the ISO-8601 standard.